# AngularJS Html not updating with data change from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started with this simple [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/wrT0ao)

From what I can tell it only uses one component. I have a project that uses multiple components. I have a cart and users clicks add button to add items to said cart. The check out component just empties the cart. I expect that when the cart is empty, the display also empties and the total would show 0.00, but that is not happening. From what I can tell the HTML only changes page load not on change of data and that is the problem, but it was my understanding that angular would take care of this on its own.

Thanks in advance

Relevant code:

app.config.js (this file has the factory and checkout functionality)

```
'use strict';

angular.
  module('floorForceApp').
  config(['$routeProvider', '$provide',
    function config($routeProvider,$provide) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
          template: '<home-page></home-page>'
        }).
        when('/floors', {
          template: '<floor-page></floor-page>'
        }).
        when('/cabinets', {
          template: '<cabinet-page></cabinet-page>'
        }).
        when('/walls', {
          template: '<wall-page></wall-page>'
        }).
        when('/checkout', {
          template: '<checkout-page></checkout-page>'
        }).
        otherwise('/home');

        
    
    },
  ]).factory('floorForceCart',function(){
    let total = 0;
    let addedItems = [];
    // let additem = function(item,price){
      
    // }

    return{
      addItems:function(item,count){
        let exist =false;

        $.each(addedItems,function(i,v){
          if(v.itemNo === item.itemNo){
            exist = true;
            v.count = v.count + count;
            total = total + (item.itemPrice*count);
          }
        });

        if(!exist){
          let toPush = {};
          toPush.itemNo = item.itemNo;
          toPush.count = count;
          toPush.itemName = item.itemName;
          toPush.itemPrice = item.itemPrice;
          addedItems.push(toPush);
          total = total + (item.itemPrice*count);
        }

        console.log("Cart:",addedItems);
        console.log("Total:",total);
      },
      removeItems: function(item,count){
        $.each(addedItems,function(i,v){
          if(v.itemNo === item.itemNo){
            v.count = v.count - count;
            total = total - (item.itemPrice * count);
            if(v.count == 0){
              addedItems.splice(i,0);
            }
          }
        });
      },
      getTotal:function(){
        return total;
      },
      getCart:function(){
        return addedItems;
      },
      checkout:function(){
        total = 0;
        addedItems = [];
        
        console.log("Check out successful.");
        console.log("Total:",total,"Cart:",addedItems);
        alert("Checkout Successful!");
      }
    };
  });
```

checkout-page.component.js (data is loaded from factory to here)

```
'use strict';

angular.
    module('checkoutPage').
    component('checkoutPage',{
        templateUrl: 'checkout-page/checkout-page.template.html',
        controller: function checkOutController($scope,$http,floorForceCart){
            let self = this;
            $scope.total = floorForceCart.getTotal();
            $scope.cart = floorForceCart.getCart();


            $scope.checkOut = function(){
                floorForceCart.checkout();
            }
        }
    })
```

checkout-page.html (this page displays the checkout)

```
<div>
    <div style="height:30em;">
        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
            <div class="row h-100">
                <div class="col-sm-4 h-100 ">
                    <div class="row prodImage h-100"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 h-100 ">
                    <div class="row h-100">
                        <div class="checkOutTitleDiv titleDiv">Checkout</div>
                        <div class="checkOutCartDiv paddingZero">
                            <div ng-repeat="item in cart" class="row marginAuto cartItemRow">
                                <div class="itemNameDiv col-sm-5">{{item.itemName}}</div>
                                <div class="itemPriceDiv col-sm-3">{{item.itemPrice|currency}}</div>
                                <div class="itemQuantityDiv col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 itemQuantity">{{item.count}}</div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkOutButtonDiv paddingZero">
                            <div class="row h-100 marginAuto">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 cartTotalDiv">
                                    <div class="">Total:{{total|currency}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input class="checkOutButton btn btn-success" ng-click="checkOut()" type="button"value="Check Out"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in the controller you add a property in the $scope referencing the same array of items referenced by the **addedItems** variable in the factory:

```
$scope.total = floorForceCart.getTotal();
$scope.cart = floorForceCart.getCart();
```

Then, when you call **checkout** from the factory, you re-assign the **addedItems** variable from the factory to a new array, and you assign a 0 to the **total** variable. The problem is that the properties $scope.total and $scope.cart doesn't have any way of knowing this. $scope.cart will still be pointing to the old array with items.

You could solve this by either:

Changing your $scope.checkOut to

```
$scope.checkOut = function(){
   floorForceCart.checkout();
   // And refresh your $scope
   $scope.total = floorForceCart.getTotal();
   $scope.cart = floorForceCart.getCart();
}
```

Or by instead of assigning a new array to addedItems  in the factory, clearing it using:

```
addedItems.length = 0;
```

If you go with the last approach, you would still have to do $scope.total = floorForceCart.getTotal(); after floorForceCart.checkout(); to update the total in your $scope.